# Page not loading in jQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have attached my Ajax and Form-When I click the button page is not getting loaded to the ajax url.On the console log i can see my url and when i copy it and run it on a separate tab it runs else its not loading and how can i see my data's passed.Anybody for help?

```js
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#excel").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var selectedMark = $("#datepicker").val();
        var selectedMark1 = $("#member_dob").val();
        if (selectedMark != "") {

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                cache:false,
                timeout:10000,
                async:true,
         url: "<?php echo base_url().'servicerecord/excel/' ?>?start=" + selectedMark + "&end=" + selectedMark1,
 
                success:function(msg)
                {
                   console.log(msg);
     window.location.href = "<?php echo base_url().'servicerecord/excel/' ?>?start=" + selectedMark + "&end=" + selectedMark1;
                },
               error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown )
    {
    console.log(textStatus);
     alert(textStatus);
    console.log(errorThrown );
    }
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

```html
<form id="search" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>servicerecord/performance" method="post" class="form-horizontal">

  <div class="panel panel-default">
   <div class="panel-heading">
   <h4 class="panel-title">Search</h4>
   
   </div>
   <div class="panel-body">

    <div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Start Date</label>
     <div class="col-sm-2">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker" name="start_date" value="<? if($this->session->userdata('start_date')){echo $this->session->userdata('start_date');}else{ echo date('d-m-Y'); } ?>">
     </div>
    
     <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">End Date</label>
     <div class="col-sm-2">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="member_dob" name="end_date" value="<? if($this->session->userdata('end_date')){echo $this->session->userdata('end_date');}else{ echo date('d-m-Y'); }?>">
     </div>
    </div>
                             
    
    
   </div><!-- panel-body -->
   <div class="panel-footer">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
     <button class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
     <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
                    <button id="excel" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-offset-9">Export to Excel</button>
                    <a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>servicerecord/pdf" class="btn btn-primary">Export to PDF</a>
    </div>
   </div>
   </div>

  </div><!-- panel -->
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
 data:{'start':'selectedMark','&end':'selectedMark1'},
```

Replace it with this;

```
 data:{'start':selectedMark,'end':selectedMark1},
```

And remove this:

```
 console.log(data);
```

EDIT:

Saw another error: was missing an `:`
Here

```
                success: function(msg) //right after success
                {
                    console.log(msg);

                },
```

The code end like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#excel").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var selectedMark = $("#datepicker").val();
        var selectedMark1 = $("#member_dob").val();

        //alert(selectedMark);
        if (selectedMark != "") {

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                cache:false,
                timeout:10000,
                async:true,

                url: "<?php echo base_url().'servicerecord/excel/' ?>",
 data:{'start' : selectedMark ,'end' : selectedMark1},

                success: function(msg)
                {
                    console.log(msg);

                },
                error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown )
                {
                console.log(textStatus);
                    alert(textStatus);
                console.log(errorThrown );
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

It should work; hope it helps.

EDIT:
Now you should the Errors in console.
And try to use the latest jQuery.

Comment: yes added and that has removed my syntax error,but it's going to the error function

Comment: I answered your primary question. If you have more information, Edit your current question and add new errors. If not, and this answer, answers your question, accept it as best answer.

Comment: Try  the new Edit. And check console.

Comment: It's goin to the success function,when i wrote alert on both the function's success alert was shown,but when  echo from controller nothing is being displayed.

Comment: Thank u brother for the help.. managed to sort out,but don't whether it's a good way to code so,i added `window.location.href = "<?php echo base_url().'servicerecord/excel/' ?>?start=" + selectedMark + "&end=" + selectedMark1;` in the success function,so that the page is being loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#excel").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var selectedMark = $("#datepicker").val();
        var selectedMark1 = $("#member_dob").val();

        //alert(selectedMark);
        if (selectedMark != "") {

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                cache:false,
                timeout:10000,
                async:true,

                url: "<?php echo base_url().'servicerecord/excel/' ?>",
                data:{'start':'selectedMark','end':'selectedMark1'},

                success function(msg)
                {
                    console.log(msg);

                },
                error:function()
                {
                    alert(fail);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

remove comma on here

```
data:{'start':'selectedMark','&end':'selectedMark1'}
```

and remove this line

```
console.log(data),//remove
success function(msg)
```

remove this too

```
// url: "<?php echo base_url() . 'servicerecord/excel/'; ?>" + selectedMark + "<?php echo '/'; ?>" + selectedMark1, //remove this
url: "<?php echo base_url().'servicerecord/excel/' ?>",
```

So final code is

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#excel").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var selectedMark = $("#datepicker").val();
            var selectedMark1 = $("#member_dob").val();

            //alert(selectedMark);
            if (selectedMark != "") {

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    cache:false,
                    timeout:10000,
                    async:true,

                    url: "<?php echo base_url().'servicerecord/excel/' ?>",
                    data:{'start':'selectedMark','&end':'selectedMark1'}

                    success function(msg)
                    {
                        console.log(msg);

                    },
                    error:function()
                    {
                        alert(fail);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script
```

Comment: bt now it shows- SyntaxError: missing } after property list

Comment: @sa-7 Edited the answer

Comment: It's still showing this error-SyntaxError: missing } after property list,and also the page is redirected to the url passed in form action instead of going to the ajax url.

Comment: On passing the values directly via the url,the error was gone but the page was not loaded.